# What is EventData doing?

Tags: probability-or-statistics

Can someone explain by a simple example what is `EventData` doing?

```
e = {1.0, 2.1, 3.2, 4.5, 5.7};
ci = {0, 0, 0, 1, 0};

A = EventData[e, ci]

Mean[A]
```

gives 3.54. How is it calculated? can someone please explain by this or another simple example.

Answer (score 2):

[Event Data >> Properties and Relations](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/EventData.html):

> *Descriptive statistics are based on the underlying [SurvivalDistribution](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SurvivalDistribution.html)*

So, as an alternative to `EmpiricalDistribution` you can also use `SurvivalDistribution` to get descriptive statistics of `A`:

```
sd = SurvivalDistribution[A]; 

{Mean@A, Mean@sd, Expectation[x, Distributed[x, sd]], 
 Dot @@ sd /@ {"Weights", "Domain"}, Dot @@ A["EmpiricalPDF"]}
```

> {3.54, 3.54, 3.54, 3.54, 3.54}

Answer (score 1):

Briefly put, one is constructing the `EmpiricalDistribution[]` from the given `EventData[]`, and then `Mean[]` is computed as usual for a discrete distribution.

Using the example in the OP:

```
e = {1.0, 2.1, 3.2, 4.5, 5.7};
ci = {0, 0, 0, 1, 0};
ed = EventData[e, ci];

dist = EmpiricalDistribution[ed];

probs = Table[Probability[k == ki, k \[Distributed] dist], {ki, e}]
   {0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0, 0.4}

{probs.e, Mean[dist], Mean[ed]}
   {3.54, 3.54, 3.54}
```